# Generically Finding Max Item in List

Tags: scala, haskell, max

In Haskell I wrote a function that, given a `List of a`, returns `Maybe a`.

```hs
max' :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
max' []     = Nothing
max' (x:xs) = Just $ foldr (\y acc -> if (y > acc) then y else acc) x xs
```

How could I write this in Scala? I'm not sure of an `Ord` equivalent in Scala.

Comment: Side comment: the folding function is strict in the accumulator, so you will get a substantial performance improvement by using [`foldl'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:foldl-39-).

Comment: thanks, luqui. Could you please say more as to the meaning of `strict`?

Comment: A function `f` is strict if evaluating `f x` always evaluates `x`.  [More here](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Performance/Strictness)  (Note that in Scala, all functions are strict)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use `scalaz.Order` or `scala.math.Ordering`:

With Scalaz:

```
def max[A](as: List[A])(implicit ord: Order[A]): Option[A] =
  as.foldLeft(None: Option[A]) {
    case (None, a) => Some(a)
    case (s @ Some(m), a) => if (ord.greaterThanOrEqual(m, a)) s else Some(a)
  }
```

Without:

```
def max[A](as: List[A])(implicit ord: math.Ordering[A]): Option[A] =
  as.foldLeft(None: Option[A]) {
    case (None, a) => Some(a)
    case (s @ Some(m), a) => if (ord.gteq(m, a)) s else Some(a)
  }
```

Note that Scalaz defines `def maximum: Option[A]` for all `Foldable` instances:

```
scala> import scalaz.syntax.foldable._
import scalaz.syntax.foldable._

scala> import scalaz.std.AllInstances._
import scalaz.std.AllInstances._

scala> List(1, 2, 3).maximum
res0: Option[Int] = Some(3)
```

The standard library defines `def max: A` for all collections, but it is unsafe:

```
scala> (Nil: List[Int]).max
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: empty.max
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Straight translate from your Haskell version:

```
scala> def max[a](vs: List[a])(implicit ord: math.Ordering[a]): Option[a] = vs match {
     |   case Nil   => None
     |   case x::xs => Some(xs.foldLeft(x)(ord.max))
     | }
max: [a](vs: List[a])(implicit ord: scala.math.Ordering[a])Option[a]

scala> max(1::2::3::4::2::Nil)
res0: Option[Int] = Some(4)

scala> max[Int](Nil)
res1: Option[Int] = None

scala> max("abcdefg".toList)
res2: Option[Char] = Some(g)
```

Or a more likely version:

```
scala> def max[a <% math.Ordered[a]](vs: List[a]): Option[a] = vs match {
     |   case Nil   => None
     |   case x::xs => Some(xs.foldRight(x){ (v, r) => if(v > r) v else r })
     | }
max: [a](vs: List[a])(implicit evidence$1: a => scala.math.Ordered[a])Option[a]

scala> max(1.0::2.3::4.5::1.6::Nil)
res4: Option[Double] = Some(4.5)
```